# How to Disable Website URL in a Web browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, url, browser

I want that any user doesn't edit my website URl.

mean that when user login in myWebsite then he/she is on studenthome.aspx and the URL(www.XXXXXX.com/studenthome.aspx) not editable.

This issue when i search on internet and getting the result in javascript code but i want c# code.
thanks

[image: Like that]

Answer (score 1):

C# is used as server side language you cannot access users' browser functionalities with C#. You need to use a client side language (JavaScript) to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you got code in javascript, you can write in c# using `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,typeof(Page), "key", "your script", true);`
Anyhow this appears in web browser.To encrypt , you can use any Script Encoder tool to encode your JavaScript.